# What does "92 in 43 in hundred" mean?

Tags: cricket

I installed glance app in my phone. It gives me wallpapers on home.

[image]

What does "92 in 43 in hundred" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Hundred' part is reference to the new competition in England called [The Hundred](https://www.thehundred.com/).

Specifically, this is showing Jemimah Rodrigues of the Northern Superchargers, who was not out with 92 runs, from 43 balls faced, in their match against Welsh Fire.